# Errors creep in when I open my android app

Tags: android

I am having this precarious situation. Today, I developed the first program in all programming languages i.e the Hello World as an app. The words Hello World was just displayed on the app. At the first instance of development, everything was perfectly fine and it even displayed on the emulator. But after a few hours, when I had restarted the system, the app did not execute and it showed an error which said "Error parsing XML build". I am really confused as to from where this error crept in which was not at all present in the first instance. Please do help rectify this error.

Comment: Can you post your code? Please post the activity code, the layout xml, and the android manifest.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Eclipse and the buggy-as-all-hell XML editor erased or moved around some lines of code in one of your XML documents. Check your error log to find out which file is having the parsing error, and check it for problems. Also, switch to IntelliJ. ;)